# Web2py: use Field represent without SQLFORM

Tags: web2py, representation

In Web2py you can assign lambda to database Field to represent it as text:
`Field('duetime', 'time', represent=lambda t,r: t.strftime("%H:%M") if t else '')`
With such description when generating SQLForm you will get nice time representation (seconds will not be shown).

But when I want to use data representation in plain HTML view, I get only raw data:

`for r in rows: print "Repr: %s Str: %s" % (r.duetime.repr(),r.duetime.str())
Repr: datetime.time(16, 15) Str: 16:15:00
Repr: None Str: None`

So it looks like only SQLForm internally generates field representations. 
How can I get query result set (Rows) containing data representation instead of raw data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Rows.render` method. For a single record:

```
rows = db(query).select()
rendered_row = rows.render(0) # apply "represent" functions to the first row
print rendered_row.duetime
```

For efficiency, you can limit to which fields the "represent" functions will be applied:

```
rendered_row = rows.render(0, fields=[db.mytable.duetime])
```

If you don't pass an index as the first argument to `.render()`, it returns a generator, allowing you to loop over all rows:

```
for row in rows.render():
    print row.duetime
```

If you want to loop over a subset of the rows, create the subset and call `.render()` on the subset:

```
for row in rows[0:10].render():
    print row.duetime
```

Details in the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Rendering-rows-using-represent).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wrote little function that takes Rows and Table as arguments and returns list of dictionaries, where keys are fields and values are their representations (almost like Rows):

`def get_rows_representation(rows,table):
    return [{f: table[f].represent(r[f],r) if table[f].represent else r[f] for f in r.as_dict()} for r in rows]`

But maybe there is a better native way to directly get Field representation from Rows?

Comment: Yes, there is a native method (`Rows.render`). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25975412/440323.